# How can I update Windows 8 RP?

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-installation

At the Win8 logon screen, it says there are essential updates to install; login and install them. How, though? I googled "Microsoft Update" which led me to the "beta.update.Microsoft" site, which simply continuously spins its wheel without getting anywhere.

Comment: What Windows 8 preview release are you using exactly?  There is no such thing as "Windows 8 RC" I think you mean Release Preview.

Comment: He's using Windows 8 RC. As far as I know, it is the latest version before RTM (Release to Manufacturing) which is not available for consumers yet

Comment: @leaf68 - Except its not called Windows 8 RC, Microsoft actually calls it `Release Preview`, there is a difference.

Comment: Oh you're right, maybe it's a typo and he meant to write RP?

Comment: @leaf68 - I don't know.  This is the reason I asked.  At this point I would just wait and install RTM, sort of pointless, to install a beta product.

Comment: More a braino than a typo.

Comment: @ClayShannon A what?

Comment: @leaf68: I simply recollected erroneously the moniker of the beta.

Comment: @ClayShannon - So update the question. Windows Update works exactly the same as it did in Windows 7 and Windows Vista.  I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't understand your confusion about my confusion. I'm trying to update, and the web site won't load. So I'm wondering if anybody knows a particular web site URL to go to (possibly it's trying to connect to the wrong one?) or another method of updating.

Comment: @ClayShannon - Are you selecting "Windows Update" from the Windows 8 Start Menu?  You update Windows 8 the same way you update Windows 7 by running Windows Update on your computer.  If beta.update.Microsoft cannot be loaded then there is a technical reason on YOUR END that is blocking it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Now we're getting somehwere - I am not aware of any Windows 8 Start Menu. How do I access it? I've always gone to http://www.update.microsoft.com/ Selecting an item from a menu would be nice and easy, but I haven't seen such a beast...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Type **Win+X** OR **right-click the bottom left** of the screen
2. Select "System"
3. In the bottom left of the new window, select "Windows Update"
4. You Win!

Alternative for 1 and 2:

1. Type **Win+Pause**

Another alternative:

1. Control Panel \ System and Security \ Windows Update, (on the address bar of windows) explorer